Using Excel VBA, how can i extract data from a named table and manipulate the data without changing the data in the original table?
In Excel VBA, I am trying to extract a unique list of values from a column in an named table. I want to store the unique list of values in a variable that I can then use for further processing. I am using the following code to do this:
    Dim SomeData As Range
     
    Set SomeData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tab") _
    
        .ListObjects("TableName").ListColumns("ColumnName").DataBodyRange  
    
    SomeData.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

However, this code removes duplicates from the underlying table - which I don't want to do.
Is there a simple way to extract the data from the table and store it in a variable that I can manipulate without changing the underlying data in the named table?

Add the values to a collection using the cell value as the key - you can't have duplicate keys in a collection.
Public Sub Test()

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim MyCol As Collection
    Set MyCol = New Collection
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab").ListObjects("TableName").ListColumns("ColumnName").DataBodyRange
        MyCol.Add Cell.Value2, Cell
    Next Cell
    
    Debug.Assert False
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 457 'This key is already associated with an element of this collection
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Module1.Test()"
    End Select

End Sub  


Or
You can use Application.Worksheetfunction.Unique:
Public Sub Test()

    Dim MyVar As Variant
    MyVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab").ListObjects("TableName").ListColumns("ColumnName").DataBodyRange)
    
End Sub  



The "Application.Worksheetfunction.Unique" works for me.

I'd suggest to use a dictionary if you want to store only unique values
Option Explicit

Sub returnNoDuplicates()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("tblData")
    
    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = lo.ListColumns("B1").DataBodyRange

    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
        ' Add the value to the dictionary
        ' If the value already exists,
        ' it will not be added again (ensuring uniqueness)
        dict(vDat(i, 1)) = vDat(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    vDat = dict.Keys
End Sub

The array vdat, like the dictionary dict,  will contain the result. It's up to you which data structure you want to use.

A workaround to save the datarange before removing duplicates, and later restore it.
Sub rest()

Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = Range("A1").ListObject
backup = lo.DataBodyRange  'save original table
lo.DataBodyRange.RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
filtered = lo.DataBodyRange 'this is the filtered result
lo.DataBodyRange.Resize(UBound(backup)) = backup  'restore original data

End Sub


This did not quite for my problem because I am referencing the name of the table rather than the cell location. When I change line 3 to appropriately reflect the table name, this code doesn't work

Do you mean that Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tab").ListObjects("TableName") doesn't work?

yes - the code will then extract all data in all columns and give the unique values across all columns, whereas I wanted unique values from a named column. (although if i use your original code as is the same problem arises)

The code is tested. The range is a cell in the table. 1 value means that it search for duplicates in the first column as in your posted code. If not gives the required result there is something which you not include in your post.

Retrieve Distinct Rows
Criteria (Single) Column
Sub RetrieveDistinctColumn()

    ' Reference the workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source objects and return the criteria column values
    ' in a 2D one-based (single-column) array.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Tab")
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("TableName")
    Dim slc As ListColumn: Set slc = slo.ListColumns("ColumnName")
    ' Assumes more than one cell.
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = slc.DataBodyRange.Value
    
    ' Retrieve the source number of rows.
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    
    ' Create and reference a dictionary object.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' A=a
    
    ' Declare addtional variables.
    Dim Value As Variant, rStr As String, sRow As Long
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the source array and return each valid (first)
    ' dictinct string representation of the criteria column in the keys,
    ' and the corresponding row index in the items (values) of the dictionary.
    For sRow = 1 To sRowsCount
        Value = sData(sRow, 1)
        If Not IsError(Value) Then ' no error
            rStr = CStr(Value)
            If Len(rStr) > 0 Then ' no blank
                If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then dict(rStr) = sRow
            End If
        End If
    Next sRow
    
    ' Define the (resulting) destination array.
    Dim dRowsCount As Long: dRowsCount = dict.Count
    If dRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only errors and blanks
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dRowsCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare addtional variables.
    Dim dRow As Long
    
    ' Loop through the keys of the dictionary and use the corresponding
    ' items, the source row indices, to write the required (dictinct) rows
    ' from the source to the destination array.
    For Each Value In dict.Items
        sRow = Value ' current source row
        dRow = dRow + 1 ' current destination row
        dData(dRow, 1) = sData(sRow, 1)
    Next Value
    
    ' Do something with the destination array ('dData')...

End Sub

All Columns
Sub RetrieveDistinctRows()

    ' Reference the workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source objects and return the source table values
    ' in a 2D one-based array.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Tab")
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("TableName")
    Dim slc As ListColumn: Set slc = slo.ListColumns("ColumnName")
    ' Assumes more than one cell.
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = slo.DataBodyRange.Value
    
    ' Retrieve the source criteria column and the number of rows and columns.
    Dim CriteriaColumn As Long: CriteriaColumn = slc.Index
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    
    ' Create and reference a dictionary object.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' A=a
    
    ' Declare addtional variables.
    Dim Value As Variant, rStr As String, sRow As Long
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the source array and return each valid (first)
    ' distinct string representation of the criteria column in the keys,
    ' and the corresponding row index in the items (values) of the dictionary.
    For sRow = 1 To sRowsCount
        Value = sData(sRow, CriteriaColumn)
        If Not IsError(Value) Then ' no error
            rStr = CStr(Value)
            If Len(rStr) > 0 Then ' no blank
                If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then dict(rStr) = sRow
            End If
        End If
    Next sRow
    
    ' Define the (resulting) destination array.
    Dim dRowsCount As Long: dRowsCount = dict.Count
    If dRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only errors and blanks
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dRowsCount, 1 To ColumnsCount)
    
    ' Declare addtional variables.
    Dim dRow As Long, Col As Long
    
    ' Loop through the keys of the dictionary and use the corresponding
    ' items, the source row indices, to write the required (dictinct) rows
    ' from the source to the destination array.
    For Each Value In dict.Items
        sRow = Value ' current source row
        dRow = dRow + 1 ' current destination row
        For Col = 1 To ColumnsCount
            dData(dRow, Col) = sData(sRow, Col)
        Next Col
    Next Value
    
    ' Do something with the destination array ('dData')...

End Sub

